Struggling with WinSCP Automating
I'm trying to automate a file transfer using WinSCP
I got this
@echo off
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" ^
 ftp://USER:PASS@IP 
 lcd C:\Users\SESAxxx\Desktop\logs
get log
exit
close

And when executing it, it opens the cmd, and logs in but risht there it gets stucked
I've typed same comands on cmd and it downloads the "log" folder
Maybe I'm skipping something in get log instruction
How may I solve it?
Thanks!
And when executing it, it opens the cmd, and logs in but risht there it gets stucked
I've typed same comands on cmd and it downloads the "log" folder
Maybe I'm skipping something in get log instruction
How may I solve it?
Thanks!
yeaad

I do thank you this reply. Solved my issue completely. :)
